# Adding image in alfresco share editor

Tags: alfresco, alfresco-share

I need to add a image from a local computer in alfresco share editor. Currently the following option is available in alfresco share editor.

[image]

This requires an url to add and I tried adding from local computer but it is not inserting anything.

The CKeditor addon (http://share-extras.github.io/addons/ckeditor-forms/) is available but it is used to insert image from the share site only.

Comment: you can upload the image in your repository and then give the right url? it is strange, i never noticed. why isn't it possible to upload an image in the editor?

Comment: Yes from repository image I can upload but how to upload files from local computer. Since I cant upload files everytime to repository and then copy the url and then insert the picture